# Why does Minecraft crash on Lubuntu but not Ubuntu?

Tags: ati, java, lubuntu, minecraft

I have **Lubuntu** and **Ubuntu** partitions **on my drive**.  I've been having an interesting time with the new lubuntu partition.  I've encountered **strange things with the game Minecraft, Java and graphics drivers on the lubuntu partition**.

Firstly, I'll say that Minecraft **runs fine at about 60fps on the Ubuntu partition** with the latest drivers. (This is lower than it should be as it's a pretty decent graphics card [Radeon HD 5700].)

When I first started lubuntu, I tried to see if I could get Minecraft running on Java.  **Java crashed when loading the main game graphics on both Sun and OpenJDK without proprietary drivers**.

Java **also crashed on both Javas with proprietary drivers** after the necessary restart.  However, after disabling (with 'remove' button) the proprietary drivers with `jockey-gtk` in the session after the restart to install the drivers, Minecraft ran very well at ~120fps.  This didn't continue after another restart, when it ran at 9fps.

After failing thereafter on lubuntu to get it working at >15fps, I tried reinstalling lubuntu and installed the exact same driver (the latest one, not the one appearing on jockey) and Java versions as on Ubuntu.  That is, **now Ubuntu and lubuntu have the same graphics driver and Java version.  Minecraft still crashes in the same way on lubuntu but works fine on Ubuntu.**  I would appreciate any explanation for any of these events.  What differences between lubuntu and Ubuntu could cause this?

> Edit:  After installing the 32bit driver version on lubuntu (seeing as
>   lubuntu is 32bit), I have Java "working" for Minecraft.  However, it
>   is at <15fps again and it can't log in to servers as it takes too
>   long.

Comment: What output does `java -version` show in terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I had Lubuntu, and it ran Minecraft fine, and I only had openjdk 6 & 7, and a friennd of mine has the same setup (software-wise, not hardware) and he runs Minecraft a little worse, I think its all about the speed of your device.

Do your drivers work? Since I got an Radeon HD 6650M, but Lubuntu and Ubuntu just ignore it and run the game on my cpu.

Answer (score -1):

I can't really help you but why don't you try to intall the Optifine Mod for Minecraft, it increases your fps a lot...
http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-125-optifine-hd-a6-fps-boost-hd-textures-aa-af-and-more/
Hope it helps you as a temporary solution :/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.